# mobiscroll image list with .click() handler

Tags: mobiscroll

When I bind a

```
$(document).on("click", '.dw-sel', function(e) { opens modal box });
```

on click, it fires each time, even when there is a drag. I want to get the click function called, only when there is a click without any draging of the wheel. Is there any of such event provided already? Or how to achieve differenciating click from drag?

EDIT:

ok, found a solution line 929 in mobiscroll.core.js

```
            if (!dist && !moved) { // this is a "tap"
        istap = true;
        tindex = Math.floor((stop - ttop) / h);
        var li = $('.dw-li', target).eq(tindex)
        li.addClass('dw-hl'); // Highlight
        setTimeout(function() {
            li.removeClass('dw-hl');
        }, 200);
    } else {
        tindex = Math.round(pos - dist / h);
        istap = false;
    }
```

I set the variable istap, and on that I based my click event.